# Go PostgreSQL: How to obtain number of rows from a db.Query?

Tags: postgresql, go

As PostgreSQL connector I import following package:

```
_ "github.com/lib/pq"
```

The query I run is:

```
res, err := db.Query("SELECT id FROM applications WHERE email='" + email + "'")
```

where email is naturally a string. One way to count the number of rows in res is by following snippet

```
count:=0
for res.Next() {
  count++
  //some other code
}
```

but there should be some simpler (and quicker) way. It seems RowsAffected() is not the way to go. So, what is your suggestion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the rows count returned from db.Query postgres](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39783780/how-to-find-the-rows-count-returned-from-db-query-postgres)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`COUNT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html) function:

```
"SELECT count(*) FROM applications WHERE email='" + email + "'"
```

Comment: Please only post answers in English

Comment: You should NOT be constructing SQL queries like this. This is prone to SQL injection, you should use prepared statements.

Comment: Kulix, I'm not totally agree with you in this case. Certainly this type of query is prone to SQL injection, but if you validate that the email var is a valid email you avoid that problem. There's different ways to solve problems, as a commentary is good your point but I don't think this is a wrong answer at all.

Comment: What happens when your validation is bugged? SQL injection. This is absolutely the wrong way to construct a SQL query in all cases.